# How to add a proxy and a header to my web scraping script in Python/BS4?

Tags: python, web-scraping, proxy, beautifulsoup

I used BeautifulSoup4 and Python to parse local html files a few times in the past. Now I would like to scrape a website using a proxy. (400 Request needed in total / after 100 request the IP does get blocked)

After slowing down my script with an ordinary 'sleep', I want to use a proxy, but I have never done this before and do need some help here. I tried two methods, with help from Stack Overflow questions:

**Method 1**
This method does work with another website, but it doesn't download data. When I 'print' the data I received, it does print "Response [200]". When I try this method with the real website, it does return an error: "Max retries exceeded with url:" I suspect the proxy is not being handled correct. When I try to read the html,  I get the following error.

> page_html = response.read()
>   AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read'
>
> ```
> response = requests.get(URL, proxies=PROXY, headers=HEADER)
> ```

**Method 2**
I was able to download another webpage, but I wasn't able to download from the original webpage (which blocked me). I assume there is a mistake with the script and the proxy isn't handled correct. Either the real IP is sent to the website, or I can't connect to the proxy:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.request.Request(url, None, header, proxy))
```

My script does look like this:

```
HEADER = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'}
URL = "https://www.website.php"
PROXY = {"https": "https//59.110.7.190:1080"}

#response.close() Is this even necessary

page_html = response.read()  # With Method 1 I also tried response.text which resulted in "str is not callable"
response.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

adresses = page_soup.findAll("li", {"class":"list-group-item"})

for address in adresses:
    try:
        #parsing the html
    except (TypeError):
        f.write("invalid data" + "\n")
time.sleep(random.randint(1, 10))
```

The error I usually get is the following:

> requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.firmendb.de', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /[website.php] (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)))
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I assume I messed up the proxy part of the script. It did work before I tried to implement it.  Because I have never done this before my main question is, is the proxy part correct?  I got the proxy from the following website: https://free-proxy-list.net/

- How to choose a proxy from these lists?
- How to connect to the proxies?
- Any suggestions on proxy-providers to use?
- Any proposal for my script?

Comment: Can you verify that your IP has changed or the requests have your real IP? You can use a site like this: https://www.whatismyip.com/my-ip-information/?iref=home to find out if your IP has changed correctly.

Comment: Also keep in mind, many proxies (particularly free proxies) are used for malicious purposes and are therefore on blacklists.

Comment: @ Christos Papoulas: Good point; I tested it and got my real IP retourned. Which means the proxy settings in the script are being ignored. Do you know why? Do you know a online help or similar for proxies and scraping? To test if the proxy worked I used this command:   response = requests.get(url, proxies={"https":"https://46.163.119.138:3128"}, headers=header)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments! The error was, that I didn't consider how often proxys would change. I wrote the proxy in my script way earlier than testing the script.

To help other, this is how the script would have to look in Pyhton3.
Of course the HEADER/URL/PROXY could also be a list and then fed trough a for loop.

```
HEADER = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'}
URL = "https://www.website.php"
PROXY = {"https": "https//59.110.7.190:1080"}

response = requests.get(URL, proxies=PROXY, headers=HEADER)
page_html = response.text
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

adresses = page_soup.findAll("li", {"class":"list-group-item"}) #for example

for address in adresses:
    try:
        #parsing the html
    except (TypeError):
        f.write("invalid data" + "\n")
time.sleep(random.randint(1, 10))
```